# Why does MemoryStream Position property change with SetLength and become immutable?

Tags: c#, immutability, memorystream

There's trouble using the System.IO.MemoryStream class.

After creating it, like so:

```
var memory = new MemoryStream();
```

it then sets the length of some bytes to write into it.

```
var length = 181;
memory.SetLength( length);
```

Then in the debugger, the memory shows the Length and
Position BOTH set to 181.  In separate simply test program
it property shows Position still at zero after `SetLength()`.

Furthermore, if I change the `Position` property to 0 using
the debugger or by adding a line of code, it ignores
and still shows 181 as the position property.  Thus it 
behaves as if immutable.

However, again in a simple unit test, this works as expected.

At first, this appeared to be a threading issue as
if MemoryStream isn't thread safe.  But in the debugger,
I froze all other threads before calling any of this code.
And it still fails as above.

Well, this is the most bizarre.  Any ideas what to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the same thing as you.  If I create a console application with the following code in Main:

```
        var x = new MemoryStream();
        x.SetLength(181);
```

..and trace past the call to `SetLength`, the debugger shows `Length` equal to 181 and `Position` equal to 0.  You *must* have something else affecting your stream object.

Comment: We must have posted at the same time. See my answer, I found the bug, it was only happening during debugging due to the debugger calling the ToString() method which I only expected to happen when logging the thing to a log file. So fixed it.

Comment: I'll give you credit for answering though. You answered so quickly and were correct.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, figured out the problem.  First clue was that it only happened in the debugger.

The cause was the the ToString() method was overridden.

It was reading the memory and displaying it in the debugger. That was reading from the memory and therefore modifying the Position.

Problem solved.

Thanks.